# batファイルで robocopy を使用し、データコピーした結果をLOGファイルに出力したい

Tags: windows, batch-file

batファイルで robocopy を使用し、**ある文字を含んだファイル名を、抽出して他フォルダへコピーしようと考えております。**
空白を含んだファイル名もコピーしたいので、下記のようなコードを書きました。

- コピー元データの保存先：fs_src
- 抽出したデータの保存先：fs_bk
- 抽出したいファイル名： name

`robocopy /s "%fs_src%" "%fs_bk%" "*%name%*.*"`

コピー結果が失敗したか成功したかを知りたいので**LOGをtxtファイルで出力しようとしています**が
下記のように書いてもなにも出ませんでした。
robocopy 文の後にLOG文 を書いておりました。

- LOG出力先指定：logdir
- LOGファイル名：target
- ログ用の日付、時刻、ファイル名設定：ToDay
- 抽出したデータの保存先：fs_bk

  `/LOG:log\%logdir%\%target%_%ToDay%.txt %%~pI %fs_bk% %%~nxI`

うまくいけばこのようなLOGテキストファイルができるはずです。

例：2020/03/30 にbatを実行した場合
　　copylog_20200330104845.txt

どなたかご教授いただけると幸いです。

Comment: バッチファイルの環境変数に関する質問か、それとも`robocopy`の引数に関する質問か、どちらでしょうか？ 問題を切り分けるべきです。

Comment: バッチファイルの1行だけとか、さらにその中の聞きたい部分だけを抜き出して質問されている感じなので、答えにくいですね。公開して問題無い程度の内容にボカして、関連する範囲の環境変数の設定やrobocopyコマンド記述を含めて全体を記述してみてください。バッチ上のrobocopyに関係ない部分ならば削っておいても構いません。

Comment: なお、バッチファイルではなくコマンドプロンプト上の手入力で実行すれば、結果が正常でもエラーでも何かしら表示されると思うので、そこから対処を考えてみるとか？

Comment: みなさんありがとうございます。
曖昧な質問ですいませんが、背景まで説明しようと…
後程詳しく加筆します。

やりたいことは、
batファイル内で、robocopyを使用したデータコピー実行でのLOG.txt出力の方法についてです。

Comment: やりたいことどうこうではなく、２つの問題のうちどちらを尋ねたいのかを明確にしてください。

Answer (score 0):

`robocopy`コマンドの表示を`>NUL 2>&1`とかで抑制するとか、バッチ自身を非表示で実行するとかしていない限り、結果が正常でもエラーでも以下のように何かしら表示されますので、そこから対処を考えてみてください。
また特に止めなければバッチが終われば表示は消えてしまうので、確認のためには`robocopy`の直後に一時的に`pause`を入れる等してください。

---

正常実行時の例：

```
 ログ ファイル: C:\Develop\LOG\EXECUTED\COPYLOG_20200401100124.TXT
```

---

エラー発生時の例：

```
2020/04/01 09:55:51 エラー 3 (0x00000003) ログ ファイルを開いています C:\Develop\LOG\EXECUTED\COPYLOG_20200401095551.TXT
指定されたパスが見つかりません。

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Windows の堅牢性の高いファイル コピー                    
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  開始: 2020年4月1日 9:55:51
   コピー元 - C:\Develop\WORKING\
     コピー先 - C:\Develop\BACKUP\20200401095551\

    ファイル: *robo*.*

  オプション: /S /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

エラー: 無効なパラメーター #5 : "/LOG:LOG\EXECUTED\COPYLOG_20200401095551.TXT"

       簡易な使用法 :: ROBOCOPY コピー元 コピー先 /MIR

           コピー元 :: コピー元ディレクトリ (ドライブ:\パスまたは \\サーバー
                       \共有\パス)。
           コピー先 :: コピー先ディレクトリ (ドライブ:\パスまたは \\サーバー
                       \\共有\パス)。
               /MIR :: 完全なディレクトリ ツリーをミラー化します。

    詳細な使用方法については、ROBOCOPY /? を実行してください。


****  /MIR はファイルをコピーできるだけでなく、削除もできます。
```

---

問題無く実行されたとして、ユーザー権限での実行時はバッチファイルの存在するフォルダまたはショートカットやシェル実行で指定した作業フォルダ/管理者権限での実行時はシステムフォルダ、の下に`log\%logdir%\%target%_%ToDay%.txt`が出来ます。探してみてください。

エラー原因で良くあるのが以下の2つです。

- 出力先パスに指定した途中のフォルダ("LOG"とか"LOG\%logdir%"(を展開したもの))が存在しない
- フォルダ名に空白が含まれているが、全体を`"`で囲っていない

なおちなみに、質問記事のパス指定方法だと、ログファイル名指定の後ろに付いている`%%~pI %fs_bk% %%~nxI`が意味不明のような気がします。

そしてログファイル名に年月日時分秒を含めているようですが、コピーするファイルが少なくて条件を変えてループ等で複数回動作させている場合、同じ秒の間に複数実行されて上書きされる可能性があるため、`/LOG:`ではなく`/LOG+:`にしておいた方が良いかもしれません。
例えばこんな記述が考えられます。

```
SET FS_SRC=C:\Develop\WORKING
SET NAME=robo
SET LOGDIR=EXECUTED
SET TARGET=COPYLOG
SET TODAY=%DATE:/=%%TIME::=%
SET TODAY=%TODAY: =0%
SET TODAY=%TODAY:~0,14%
SET FS_BK=C:\Develop\BACKUP\%TODAY%
MKDIR %FS_BK%
ROBOCOPY "%FS_SRC%" "%FS_BK%" "*%NAME%*.*" /S /LOG+:"LOG\%LOGDIR%\%TARGET%_%TODAY%.TXT"
```

参考記事：
[robocopyでバックアップした時のログファイルを日付毎に作成する方法（＋過去の古いファイルの削除方法も）](https://amaotolog.com/backup/entry190.html)